# Hiding or Adding?

Tags: python, kivy, widget, hide, show

I want to create an app in Python Kivy but I have stuck in some part. I want some additional show-ups in my app. Briefly, that is a selection app. So after make some sellections and and press "calculate" button, I want to show some hidden results. And when you confirm those results you should press "confirm" button that shows new selections which were hidden as well.

I can make it with BooleanProperty but in that case when height: "0dp" and opacity: 0, it still keeps unwanted empty space in widget. How can I get rid of the empty space ?

little comment: when you make opticity 1 while height:"0dp" remain, you will see they are still there. height 0 is not working properly.

here my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
    def btn(self):
        popup = Popup(content=Label(text='Wrong Password'),
        size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 200))
        popup.bind(on_touch_down=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)
    bisShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__== "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

and here is my.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<ScrollViewExample@ScrollView>:
    SecondWindow:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height


<Button>:
    size_hint: .35 , 1
    height: "20dp"
    width: "20dp"

    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"

    BoxLayout:

        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        orientation: "vertical"
        Image:
            source:"vgs.png"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: "110dp"
            allow_stretch: True 
            keep_ratio: False

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x:"center"
            anchor_y:"center"


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: "10dp"
                size_hint: .8,.3

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text: "Username:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    TextInput:
                        id: username
                        text: "***"
                        multiline: False

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text: "Password:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    TextInput:
                        id: password
                        text: "***"
                        multiline: False


                BoxLayout:
                    #orientation:"horizontal"
                    CheckBox:
                        color: 0,0,0,1

                        
                    Label:    
                        text: "Remember me"
                        color: 0,0,0,1


                Button:
                    size_hint: .35 , 1
                    text: "Login"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

                    on_release: 
                        #root.btn() if username.text!="batu" or password.text!="1010" else None
                        app.root.current= "second" #if username.text=="batu" and password.text=="1010" else "main" 
                        root.manager.transition.direction="left"


<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols:1 
            height: self.minimum_height 
            row_default_height: "60dp"
            size_hint_y: None
            spacing:"10dp"
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Image:
                source:"vgs.png"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "110dp"
                allow_stretch: True 
                keep_ratio: False

            BoxLayout:
                pading:"10dp"
                spacing:"10dp"
                orientation: "vertical"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text:"Solid Content:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    TextInput:
                        text:"enter %"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text:"Pressure:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    TextInput:
                        text:"enter BAR"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                                    
            Button:
                text:" Model Selection"
                height: "20dp"
                width: "20dp"            


            Button:
                text:" Screen Selection"

            Button:
                text:"Rotor Selection"

            
            Button:
                text:"Motor & Reduction Selection"



            Button:
                text:"Calculate Selections"
                on_press: root.isShownMenu = not root.isShownMenu


            BoxLayout:
                pading:"10dp"
                spacing:"10dp"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "0dp" if root.isShownMenu else "80dp"
                opacity: 0 if root.isShownMenu else 1


                orientation: "vertical"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text:"Calculated Flow:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    Label:
                        text:"enter %"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text:"Calculated Pressure:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    Label:
                        text:"00000"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"horizontal"
                    Label:
                        text:"Fibre Lenght:"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                    Label:
                        text:"000000"
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                Button:
                    on_press: root.bisShownMenu = not root.bisShownMenu
                    text:"Confirm"

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "0dp" if root.bisShownMenu else "80dp"
                opacity: 0 if root.bisShownMenu else 1
                orientation:"horizontal"
                Label:  
                    text:"cutter head material"
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                Button:
                    text:"1.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"2.secim"                    
                Button:
                    text:"3.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"4.secim"

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "0dp" if root.bisShownMenu else "80dp"
                opacity: 0 if root.bisShownMenu else 1
                orientation:"horizontal"
                Label:  
                    text:"screen material"
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                Button:
                    text:"1.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"2.secim"                    
                Button:
                    text:"3.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"4.secim"

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "0dp" if root.bisShownMenu else "80dp"
                opacity: 0 if root.bisShownMenu else 1
                orientation:"horizontal"
                Label:  
                    text:"blade material"
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                Button:
                    text:"1.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"2.secim"                    
                Button:
                    text:"3.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"4.secim"

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "0dp" if root.bisShownMenu else "80dp"
                opacity: 0 if root.bisShownMenu else 1
                orientation:"horizontal"
                Label:  
                    text:"pot material"
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                Button:
                    text:"1.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"2.secim"                    
                Button:
                    text:"3.secim"
                Button:
                    text:"4.secim"


            Button:
                size_hint: .35 , 1
                text: "Login"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                on_release: 
                    app.root.current= "main" 
                    root.manager.transition.direction="right"
```

sorry for long codes. maybe it helps you in some parts.

Comment: please add some random png file in your folder with same name to see the results.

Comment: Your code is too big please add some comments on .kv file so that will let us know about which button,.. you are taking about.That will help us to answer your question quickly.

Comment: Thank you Abhay. Please see my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.

Well, if you want to add a different class to main your main class with a button or something, you should use "add_widget". But while you doing it, you need to convert your class to objectproperty first and than, use ids for id of your main widget;

```
    cal2= ObjectProperty()
    def btn4(self):
        self.cal2 = MaterialS() #MaterialS is my class with different widget
        self.ids.scd.add_widget(self.cal2, index=0)  #scd is the id of my main widget, index =0 help me to insert to the bottom
```